# Swift, Custom Pixel Grid Mask Effect

Tags: ios, swift, mask, cashapelayer

**How can I implement text and emoji display similar to pixel grid?**

I suppose, i can use alot Views and `CAShapeLayer` as a Mask.
I really hope for any guess, thansk.

[image]
or
[image]